# Leaflet ignore click event when popup is open

Tags: leaflet, popup, events

I am building a tool allowing to edit some GeoJSON props on a popup opened over the GeoJSON element/layer. When the popup is closed the props are shown in a fixed tooltip over the polygon.
However, the popup always opens and closes even if the popup is already open. Is there a way to prevent that?
In other words, is there a way for the GeoJSON layer to ignore a click event on the polygon if the popup is already open?

[*Demo fiddle*](https://jsfiddle.net/jStefano/m43es72a)

```js
var geojson = { "type": "Feature", "properties": {"name":"my poly"}, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -0.11810302734375, 51.57706953722565 ], [ -0.29937744140625, 51.469407923261336 ], [ 0.098876953125, 51.354631230360226 ], [ 0.17303466796874997, 51.50190410761811 ], [ -0.11810302734375, 51.57706953722565 ] ] ] } };

var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON(geojson);

geojsonLayer
  .on('popupopen', (e) => {
    geojsonLayer.closeTooltip();
    geojsonLayer.getPopup().setLatLng(
      geojsonLayer.getBounds().getCenter()
    );
  })
  .on('popupclose', (e) => {
    geojsonLayer.openTooltip();
  })
  .bindTooltip((layer) => `Name: <b>${layer.feature.properties.name}</b>`, {
    permanent: true,
    interactive: false,
    direction: 'center',
  })
  .bindPopup((layer) => `
    <form>
    <h3>Edit</h3>
    <input type="text" value="${layer.feature.properties.name}" />
    </form>
  `)
  .addTo(map)

map
  .fitBounds(geojsonLayer.getBounds())
```

Comment: Cross-posted as https://stackoverflow.com/q/73452308/820534

Comment: Coding question on GIS SE site should include relevant existing code. Please edit your question and add relevant existing code.

Comment: @TomazicMI linked a jsfiddle in my question, is that not ok?

Comment: Q/A on GIS SE site are not intended only to solve problem of particular user, but be helpful resource for anybody with similar questions/problems. That's the reason question has to be complete in itself and include all relevant code as text, since outside links tend to get lost in time and also that there is no need to visit other sites to get complete picture of what the problem/question is. Also reduce your question to only one question  (now you have three), otherwise it will stay closed and won't be eligible for answers.

Comment: @TomazicM I edited the question, thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to achieve desired behavior would be to create stand alone popup and then on feature `click` event fill it with content, put it to the right place and show on the map.

To avoid flickering popup option `closeOnClick: false` has to be used and on map `click` event popup has to be closed.

Code could then look something like this:

```
var popup = L.popup({
  closeOnClick: false
});

const geojsonLayer = L.geoJSON(geojson, {
  onEachFeature: (f, l) => {
    l.on('click', (e) => {
      L.DomEvent.stopPropagation(e);
      popup.setLatLng(
        geojsonLayer.getBounds().getCenter()
      );
      popup.setContent(
        `<form>
           <h3>Edit</h3>
           <input type="text" value=` + f.properties.name + ` />
         </form>`
      );
      popup.openOn(map);
    });
  }
});

map.on('click', (e) => {
  map.closePopup();
});2
```